# A path command not properly positioning a node in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

In the following diagram, I want the node containing the label "P" to be placed at the other endpoint of the gray line segment. Why is the "P" being typeset at the origin?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}

\usepackage{mathtools,array}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}





\begin{document}



\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}



%Part of an ellipse and a parabola are drawn.
\draw (0,0) arc (0:90: 2 and 1);
\draw (0,0) arc (0:-72: 2 and 1);
\path node[anchor=east] at ({-2+sqrt(31)/8},-15/16){$E_{1}$};
\draw[fill] (0,0) circle (1.5pt);
%A "pin" is drawn between (0,0) and its label.
\draw[draw=gray, line width=0.8pt, shorten <=1.5mm, shorten >=0mm] (0,0) -- ({(atan(1/3)+90)/2}:0.75);
\path node[anchor=south] ({(atan(1/3)+90)/2}:0.75){$P$};
%
\draw[domain=-1:4, smooth, variable=\x, blue] plot ({\x}, {-1/9*\x*\x + 1/3*\x});
\path node[anchor=south west, xshift=-0.5mm, yshift=-1mm] at (3.75,-5/16){$E_{2}$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You were missing an `at`:

```
\path node[anchor=south] at ({(atan(1/3)+90)/2}:0.75) {$P$};
```

You just named the node `{(atan(1/3)+90)/2}:0.75`.

Though, since you already have a path to that coordinate, you can just add the node there:

```
\draw[draw=gray, line width=0.8pt, shorten <=1.5mm, shorten >=0mm] (0,0)
  -- ({(atan(1/3)+90)/2}:0.75) node[anchor=south] {$P$};
```

---

I've taken the liberty to re-write your picture with the newer `arc` syntax that is PGFkeys powered which would allow you to set specific values, say the radii, outside of `arc[]` and it would be used for all arcs that are included in the path/scope/group.

I've also used the the [`parabola` path operation](https://tikz.dev/tikz-paths#pgf.parabola) that not only let's you specify the bend but also its position or the parabola's height (see the manual for more on that).

TikZ also has a [`pin` option](https://tikz.dev/tikz-shapes#tikz/pin) to be used with coordinates and labels but it might not precise enough for you, depending on where the angle `(atan(1/3)+90)/2` comes from.

### Code

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw ([shift=(left:2)] -72:2 and 1) node[left]{$E_1$}
      arc [start angle=-72, end angle=90, x radius=2, y radius=1];

\draw[fill] (0,0) circle [radius=1.5pt];

\draw[draw=gray, line width=0.8pt, shorten <=1.5mm, shorten >=0mm] (0,0)
  -- ({(atan(1/3)+90)/2}:0.75) node[anchor=south] {$P$};

\draw[blue] (-1, -1/9-1/3) parabola bend (1.5, -.25+.5) (4, -16/9+4/3) node[right] {$E_2$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 Where can I read about `(left:2)`?

Comment: @hpekristiansen [At the bottom of the subsection about the polar canvas coordinate system.](https://tikz.dev/tikz-coordinates#pgf.canvas:polar) Though, it also applies to the polar xy coordinate system. If TikZ parses a polar coordinate it just checks if the part before `:` is one of the defined directions and replaces it with the proper degree number. It's just a special alias. You could add one yourself by doing `\def\tikz@polar@dir@ten{10}` → `(ten:2)`. I use it as a "speaking" direction instead of `180` (and not have to protect the `,` in `(-2,0)`).

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel  Thanks for finding my mistake in my code. Ugghhh. The direction for my "pin" is halfway between the vertical tangent to the ellipse at P and the tangent to the parabola at P.

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) arc[start angle=0, end angle=90, x radius=2, y radius=1];
\draw (0,0) arc[start angle=0, end angle=-72, x radius=2, y radius=1] node[left]{$E_{1}$};
\draw[blue] plot[domain=-1:4, smooth] ({\x}, {-1/9*\x*\x + 1/3*\x}) node[above]{$E_{2}$};
\fill (0,0) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[draw=gray, thick, shorten <=1.5mm] (0,0) -- (50:0.8) node[above right, inner sep=1pt]{$P$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Two curves and labels]